# Add copy button to swagger in .Net Core 6 web API

Tags: .net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I built a REST API with .net core 6 and added swagger UI to it.
When I run the API, I don't see the copy-to-clipboard button when I hover over the routes.
How do I add it?

These are my installed packages:

[image]

Comment: What version of Swagger UI do you use? (Open the browser console > Console tab > evaluate `versions`.) The "copy path to clipboard" button was added in [v. 4.13](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases/tag/v4.13.0).

Comment: I'm using version 3.52.1. How do I upgrade it?

Comment: If you use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore or Swagger-Net - update that library to the latest version. If you host Swagger UI assets directly - take the latest [dist](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) assets.

Comment: I updated the library to the latest version (6.5.0), and I still get 3.52.1 version. Any other idea?

Comment: It could be that your browser is showing the cached version. If you clear the browser cache, do you see the updated version?

Comment: Tried to clean the cache. No changes. Still doesn't show the copy button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the copy button not showing on 6.5.0 version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. I downgraded it to 6.4.0 and now the icon is there.